# Reduce transparency and Lock-screen Background

Tags: graphics, macos

I'm running El captain public beta but I think this also applies to macs running Yosemite. I really like the look of the reduce transparency + increase contrast in Yosemite/El Captain. Unfortunately those options also force the lock screen background to be a boring grey colour instead of the blurred version of my desktop background :(

I am aware that you [can change](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/custom-login-screen-wallpaper-os-x-yosemite/) the lock/login screen background by navigating to /Library/Caches and changing a file. I checked and the file is as it should be - the blurred version of my desktop background.

Is there a way to set the lock screen background to something other than the grey colour while still keeping reduce transparency and increase contrast on? Perhaps something to do with changing system files?

EDIT: I did some research and it seams like this behaviour is unique to El Captain. Yosemite has the desired behaviour of the lock screen being the blurred background even with reduce transparency and increased contrast turned on

Answer (score -1):

I have had this question as well for a long time and my answer is — as far as I can tell and have tried and researched in other posts and fora — there is no way to do so. Hopefully that assertion will motivate someone to try and find an answer that proves me wrong.

As of 2017 the issue you are having is also present in MacOS Sierra — to respond to the claim that it is unique to El Capitan — making the issue still relevant. I have asked this question myself recently on apple.stackexchange but nobody has responded as of yet.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/196719)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question perhaps, but it adds to the question by affirming that the same problem is present in MacOS Sierra, which is a response to the claim that the issue is unique to El Capitan. If you read my comment you'd see that I have asked the same question already and as a result of not receiving any help I opted to contribute to the question that was asked earlier and has received more attention. Clearly I don't have enough reputation to add a bounty.

Comment: you didn't post a comment, you posted an answer

Comment: That's because I am not able to post a comment.

Comment: I have updated my answer/comment in order to reflect your concerns. Thank you.